# Use Align only once for two text widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Widget _createProfileContainer() {
    return new Container(
        height: 64.0,
        child: new Row(children: [
          new Expanded(
              child: new Container(
                  color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                  child: new Column(children: [
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: new Text("Today",
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 19.0, color: Colors.black))),
                    Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: new Text("Thuersday, 26 March"))
                  ]))),
        ]));
  }
```

Nice it's work fine. Both text (**Today** and **Thuersday, 26 March**) are align on left. But I apply **Align** twice. Is it possible to apply Align only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [crossAxisAlignment  property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CrossAxisAlignment-class.html) to align all children in column

```dart
Column(
    children: [
        Text("Today",
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 19.0, color: Colors.black
            )
        ),
        Text("Thuersday, 26 March")
    ],
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Remove both `Align()`s and wrap the Column widget in `Center()`

2) Set `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` for the Column widget, and for both Text widgets set `textAlign: TextAlign.center`